# How to increase the font of packet tracer

Tags: kubuntu, themes, fonts

Kubuntu. I am with sweet theme, with kvantum engine activated too and the font is so tiny that I can't read. I tried to increasing font size inside the program but the icons will be terribly big[image] Im using KDE

This is happening in various apps, here in anki too:
[image]

Kwin turned off because I have multiple refresh monitors.

````
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute```
````

Comment: Does it happen for all software or this particular software? If so, which software is this? Please edit your question.

Comment: Also please specify Ubuntu  version, desktop/flavor, CPT version.

Comment: I found a not so clean way to fix the problem, in font dpi I increase to 125 dpi. And In monitors -> global scale I set to 125%. But I feel that is not the best way to solve it...